# How Do I Change The Cursor Url Default Background Color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

Whenever I use a custom cursor(`cursor:url('');`) and drag the cursor towards the bottom of the taskbar, the cursor would have a white background. I don't know why that would happen when I am using a .png file. is there any attribute to `:url` or any workaround to remove the background, or is it an indefinite cursor setting?

Comment: Just because you are using a `.png` doesn't mean that there is a transparent background. You'd have to set that up in some image editing software and save the file that way. Also, older browsers have issues with transparent `.png` files.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The image already has a transparent background.

Comment: Please post the image. Also try to turning it to a gif.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Love-heart-arrow.svg this is the image that I'm using.

Comment: @ChristianPastorCruz or you can go here: https://www.google.com/search?q=arrow+heart&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=isz:m&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9te2XnYXZAhUEM6wKHTn_C5wQpwUIIA&biw=1866&bih=1021&dpr=0.9&safe=active&ssui=on#imgrc=A2WvuhXyrR4VMM:

Comment: That's an .svg, not a .png (which is better).

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yep! you had the right idea. I saved a png heart and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

To be used as cursor, images should be small enough. Resize to 64x64 will do.

Comment: This is not an answer. It doesn't explain the problem or have a definite solution. It should be a comment. Also, .svg images have transparent backgrounds by default.

Comment: Why don't you delete your answer and add this as a comment?

Comment: This is still a comment. You haven't definitively said what the problem is/was. You're just giving advice (albeit good advice). This still should be a comment, not an answer.